# Templates: why do we use <%= tag for a for-loop/comprehension?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For instance:

```
<table>
  <%= for user <- @users do %>
    <tr>
      <td><b><%= first_name(user) %></b> (<%= user.id %>)</td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

According to Programming Phoenix 1.4 (ebook, beta):

> EEx executes Elixir code that’s within <%= %> tags, injecting the
>   result into the template. EEx evaluates code within <% %> tags without
>   injecting the result. We’ll try to use code without side effects in
>   views wherever possible, so we’ll use mostly the <%= %> form.

As a counter example, in Rails you would write:

```
<table>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
```

Comment: The correct tag is `phoenix-framework` not `phoenix`

Answer (score 4):

Comparing it to [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) doesn't make sense, because [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is an immutable, functional language and by design, everything in Elixir returns *something* since you can't modify state. This includes [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) like `for` which return a list of the new values calculated. As a simple example, see what a basic comprehension returns:

```ex
for user <- @users, do: full_name(user)
# => ["John Case", "Mak Ali", "Sarah Middleton"]
```

Second, `EEx` allows two ways for executing code in templates:

- `<% %>` which executes the statements, but ***throws away the result***, and
- `<%= %>` which executes the statements and ***injects the result*** into the template

---

> But we're already using `<%= %>` for child elements in the comprehension, *so they should still be injected into the template, right?*

No. At this point they are still inside the `for` block, so even though the child elements with the full name are computed, **they aren't rendered because the result of the comprehension itself isn't included**.

<sup>A better comparison in [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) would be the [form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). If you don't use `<%= >` for the main `form` tag, the entire form doesn't get rendered, even if you use it for the child tags. That's because the children are inside it, and can only be rendered when the form itself is rendered.</sup>

---

The `EEx` engine later concatenates all list elements into the template. You can try this out yourself:

```ex
EEx.eval_string("Numbers: <%= list %>", list: ~w[1 2 3])
#=> "Numbers: 123"

EEx.eval_string("Numbers: <%= for i <- list do %> <b><%= i %></b> <% end %>", list: ~w[1 2 3])
#=> "Numbers:  <b>1</b>  <b>2</b>  <b>3</b> "

EEx.eval_string("Numbers: <% for i <- list do %> <b><%= i %></b> <% end %>", list: ~w[1 2 3])
#=> "Numbers: "
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what a comprehension does: it iterates over a list, and collects a transformation of each input. Though it looks like a for loop, what you're really doing is generating and collecting a series of HTML fragments, which all then get combined and injected into the template once the comprehension returns.

If it were Ruby, a rough equivalent might be:

```
<%= @users.map {|user| generate_fragment(user) }.join %>
```

If you were to write:

```
<% @users.map {|user| generate_fragment(user) }.join %>
```

your code would run, but it would produce no output, because `generate_fragment` returns a string, rather than directly emitting to a template collector.

Remember that in functional languages, you give input to a function and operate on the return value of that function - proper functional code should have no side effects. Writing to a template collector as a result of a function invocation would be a side effect!

Comment: *what you're really doing is generating and collecting a series of HTML fragments, which all then get combined and injected into the template once the comprehension returns.* -- I don't think that's any different than in Rails.  Elixir/Phoenix are languages that were created to make erlang more like ruby.  In rails, if you used `<%=` with an expression that returned a list, then the actual list would be displayed on the web page.  So my question is why Phoenix is using the same Rails syntax for doing something that seems completely different...

Comment: ...In Phoenix, why would the result of the comprehension need to be injected into the template when it's the individual items that need to get injected in the template?  Is the comprehension result actually assigned to a hidden variable that is then iterated over at a later date?

Comment: `Elixir [...] were created to make Erlang more like Ruby`. No, that's not correct. Jose has taken as much inspiration from Clojure as Ruby (if not more). That aside, the _"individual items"_ are still inside the `for` block, and to include them you _will_ have to inject the comprehension's result as well. See my updated answer for a better explanation.